Simply connectedness of leaves of a foliation on an complex manifold
Now I'm searching about leaves of foliation in the following special setting.
Let $U,V$ be two holomorphic vector field on $\mathbb{C}^2$ s.t the Lie bracket $[U,V]=UV-VU=0$ and $U$ and $V$ spaned each tangent space.
Especially, they are non-vanishing.
So $U$ and $V$ are like standard two complex vector fields $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$
Then what is like each foliation  of $U$ and $V$. Do these look like those of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$  ?
In particular, are leaves of $U$ and $V$ simply conneceted as standard coordinate line of $\mathbb{C}^2$?
Here is a example of such $U$ and $V$. But I don't know how to caluculate its genus.
Could you tell me its genus?
Example
$U=e^y\frac{d}{dx}$ and $V=xe^y\frac{d}{dx}-e^{-y}\frac{d}{dy}$
Here
$det\begin{bmatrix}e^y&xe^y\\0&-e^{-y}\end{bmatrix}=1$
$UV=VU=e^{2y}\frac{d}{dx}+xe^{2y}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}$
So $U$ and $V$ satisfies the condition.
Edit:
I calculated each leaf of $U$ and $V$
$U$:connected component of $e^{-y}=c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{C}$
$V$:connected component of $x=ce^{-y}$ for some $c\in \mathbb{C}$
So each leaves is holomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$
